# How to rewrite wordpress URL?

Tags: php, wordpress

Following is my post URL.

http://animoplus.localhost/races-chiens/category2/category-2-first-post/

// here post name is below

- races-chiens/category2/category-2-first-post/

Now, I want to create other URL for photos section for the same post like below.

http://animoplus.localhost/races-chiens/category2/category-2-first-post/photos

How can I handle it wordpress?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.wpexplorer.com/change-permalinks-wordpress/ its all in the permalinks. google a bit with the permalinks, there is a lot possible there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your words "photos section" mean the same page's area, you have 2 options:

1. Change your path to http://animoplus.localhost/races-chiens/category2/category-2-first-post/#photos (note # sign before photos) and add id="photos" attribute to your photos container (how it works - [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) in "HTML Links - The id Attribute" section).
2. Use [Wordpress internal rewrites](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) to forward all your /post-name/* URLs to your post's page, then on your post page determine this case (e.g. analyze your current URL) and add needed javascript to scroll to your photos section (or show it).

If your "photos section" means another page, use #2 and route these URLs to pages you need. I'd suggest to use the first option.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by giving your **custom url** in the **link to** section in **attachment display settings** in time of inserting your media file into post.

I hope it may work for you.